# How to use mock.patch with wraps on a class method？

Tags: python, mocking

I am using `unittest.mock.patch` with `wraps` to mock a function while being able to access the original function. For example:

```py
from unittest import mock

def f(x, y):
    return x * y

print(f(2, 3))  # output: 6

original_f = f
def m(x, y):
    return original_f(x, y + 1)

with mock.patch('__main__.f', wraps=m) as mk:
    print(f(2, 3))  # output: 8
```

However, a similar program that tries to mock a class method does not work:

```py
from unittest import mock

class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def f(self, y):
        return self.x * y

a = A(2)

print(a.f(3))  # output: 6

original_f = A.f
def m(self, y):
    return original_f(self, y + 1)

with mock.patch('__main__.A.f', wraps=m) as mk:
    print(a.f(3))  # Exception
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(a.f(3))
          ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/mock.py", line 1118, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/mock.py", line 1122, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/unittest/mock.py", line 1192, in _execute_mock_call
    return self._mock_wraps(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: m() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

It appears that the mock package tries to call `m(self=3, y=<undefined>)`, so the exception happens.

Why does `mock.patch` with `wraps` fail to work on class methods? How should I fix my program?

**Edit:**

Here is a more complicated working example, to demonstrate that

1. The `a.f(3)` call cannot be modified.
2. The tester (`run_test`) cannot access `a` in testee (`test_target`).

```py
from unittest import mock

class A:
    # This class cannot be changed
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def f(self, y):
        return self.x * y

def test_target():
    # This function cannot be changed
    a = A(2)
    b = A(3)
    return a.f(3), b.f(3)

def run_test():
    print(test_target())  # output: (6, 9)

    original_f = A.f
    def m(self, y):
        return original_f(self, y + 1)

    with mock.patch('__main__.A.f', wraps=m) as mk:
    #with mock.patch.object(A, 'f', wraps=m) as mk:
        print(test_target())  # Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Change the call to method `f()`

A solution is change the call to the method f of the class A.
This change is showed in the code below:

```
from unittest import mock

class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def f(self, y):
        return self.x * y

a = A(2)

print(a.f(3))  # output: 6

original_f = A.f
def m(self, y):
    return original_f(self, y + 1)

with mock.patch('__main__.A.f', wraps=m) as mk:
    #print(a.f(3))  # Exception
    print(a.f(a, 3))  # CHANGE THE CALL TO method f()
```

### Remove the `self` argument from function `m()`

Or if you prefer *remove the `self` attribute from the function `m()`*:

```
from unittest import mock

class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def f(self, y):
        return self.x * y

a = A(2)

print(a.f(3))  # output: 6

original_f = A.f

#def m(self, y):                        
#    return original_f(self, y + 1)
def m(y):   # <--- Remove the self attribute from m()
    return original_f(a, y + 1)   # <--- Pass a to original_f

with mock.patch('__main__.A.f', wraps=m) as mk:
    print(a.f(3))
```

---

**EDIT:**
I have modified the answer to react to the edit of the question. A possible code for solve the problem could be the following:

```
from unittest import mock

class A:
    # This class cannot be changed
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def f(self, y):
        return self.x * y

def test_target():
    # This function cannot be changed
    a = A(2)
    b = A(3)
    return a.f(3), b.f(3)

def run_test():
    print(test_target())  # output: (6, 9)

    original_f = A.f

    # your m() function
    #def m(self, y):
    #   return original_f(self, y + 1)

    def m(self, y):
        self.x = 2 # emulate a = A(2)
        return original_f(self, y + 1)

    def m2(self, y):
        self.x = 3 # emulate b = A(3)
        return original_f(self, y + 1)

    with mock.patch.object(A, 'f') as mk:
        mk.side_effect = [m(A, 3), m2(A, 3)]    # <--- here I have used side_effect
        print(test_target())  # output (8, 12)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test()
```

I have created 2 functions:

- `m()` which adds the attribute x=2 to class `A` (this emulate the instance `a=A(2)`)
- `m2()` which adds the attribute x=3 to class `A` (this emulate the instance `b=A(3)`)

The other changed is the use of `side_effect` and this causes:

- when the function `test_target()` calls `a.f(3)` the function `f` is substituted by `m(A,3)`
- when the function `test_target()` calls `b.f(3)` the function `f` is substituted by `m2(A,3)`

Comment: Unfortunately these solutions do not work for my case. I am unittesting a separate file. `a` is defined inside a function, so I cannot access `a` from `with mock.patch ...`. The call `a.f(3)` is also performed in the function, so I cannot change it to `a.f(a, 3)`.

Comment: Please can you edit the question so I can see better your code?

Comment: @EricStdlib I think that you can use `mock.patch.object()` instead of `mock.patch()`, but without see exactly your code I'm not able to improve the answer.

Comment: I have updated the question to better represent the actual situation. However, it looks like `mock.patch.object` also does not work.